# Excel is not refreshing using refreshall method in powershell script

Tags: excel, powershell

I have PowerShell script which refreshs the excel from SharePoint to share drive location. I'm passing the credentials through `.bat` file but the credentials are not passing to excel when I use `$excelworkbook.RefreshAll()` method and prompting to enter the credentials again. *IF* I remove the parenthesis from refreshall then script will run but it is not refreshing the sheets data.

Your help will be appreciated.
Regards,
Raju

```
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application

$excel.visible = $true

$fname = Split-Path $workbookpath -Leaf

storedp "$destpath" "Refreshing workbook"

$tempPath = "c:Temp\Autosys"
Copy-Item "$workbookpath" "$tempPath"
$excelworkbook = $excel.workbooks.Open("$tempPath\$fname")   
$excelworkbook.RefreshAll()  


while ($excelworkbook.ODBCConnection.Refreshing)
{
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

$excelworkbook.save()
$excelworkbook.close()
$excel.quit()
$DSN = $args[0]
$DB = $args[1]
$DB_User = $args[2]
$DB_Password = $args[3]
$SQLServerPwd = $args[4]
$NetworkPwd = $args[5]
$SingleOrBulk = $args[6]
$Filename = $args[7]
$OutFilename = $args[8]
$Dated = $args[9]
$DateFormat = $args[10]
write-host "DSN = $DSN"
write-host "DB = $DB"
write-host "DB_User = $DB_User"
write-host "DB_Password = $DB_Password"
write-host "SQLServerPwd = $SQLServerPwd"
write-host "NetworkPwd = $NetworkPwd"
write-host "SingleOrBulk = $SingleOrBulk"
write-host "Filename = $Filename"
write-host "OutFilename = $OutFilename"
$pass= $NetworkPwd | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force   
$cred=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('test@prod',$pass)
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\testprod.md.net\GroupShares\Global\PA" -Credential $cred

$cred=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('test@dev',$pass)
```

Comment: Please post your script here

Comment: $excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application

    $excel.visible = $true

    $fname = Split-Path $workbookpath -Leaf

    storedp "$destpath" "Refreshing workbook"

    $tempPath = "c:Temp\Autosys"
    Copy-Item "$workbookpath" "$tempPath"
    $excelworkbook = $excel.workbooks.Open("$tempPath\$fname")
    #dataConnection $excelworkbook   
    $excelworkbook.RefreshAll()

Comment: while ($excelworkbook.ODBCConnection.Refreshing)
    {
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
   
    $excelworkbook.save()
    $excelworkbook.close()
    $excel.quit()

Comment: Hi Manu, added the code. Can you pls help

Comment: Edit your first post because in the comments, the code is unreadable because not formatted

Comment: code added in first post

Comment: $excelworkbook.RefreshAll() method asking the password but I'm passing through windows batch file. Can you pls help

Comment: Hi Manu, Getting error :Exception calling "RefreshAll" with "0" argument(s): "SQL Syntax Error"
At C:\Temp\Scripts\Autosys\Excel\RefreshExcelPB.ps1:66 char:5
+     $excelworkbook.RefreshAll()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by putting the connection details in internet explorer in local connections tab.

Comment: Again, please post your script to provide an answer to others who are having the same issue.

Comment: Script posted above, no changes to it